# how to run PACT Broker can-i-deploy script?

Tags: pact, pact-broker, pact-net

i have downloaded the zip file https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker-client#can-i-deploy  and running the below command in my bash but i am getting error, what i am doing wrong

my plan was to run this can-i-deploy  from C# code but before that i am running through curl but facing issue, any help is appreciated 
[image]
sample script :

```
curl pact-broker.bat can-i-deploy --pacticipant clientpact --version 1.0.1.6 --broker-base-url http://devas.company.com
```

Error:
curl: option --pacticipant: is unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you prefixing the command with `curl`? I think that's your problem.

`curl` is a tool for doing HTTP requests, `pact-broker.bat` is the CLI tool.